# CSS width issues with HTML Table

Tags: php, html, css, width, css-tables

I would consider myself proficient in CSS and HTML but I cannot figure out this issue with one of my columns in an HTML table. Here's the link:

http://stormaware.net/reports.php

I've been working at it for a quite a while and have used fixed widths, min-widths, max-widths and can't figure out how to get the last columns (under comments) to size correctly when the table decreases in size. If you decrease and increase the browser window, you'll see the table resize to fit. The final column pops down to the next line though when you decrease the browser window enough.

I'm aware that this is not responsive, etc, we're doing work on all of that later but for right now I'm just trying to get the content in the comments column to decrease in width and fit in it's own column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you floating your table elements? Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me when I was testing it in Chrome.. also it was a little glitchy..

```
th[scope="row"] table.reports_table tr td {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    color: black;
    float: left; /*Remove this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content grows more than the table size, it will generally overflow. set the table layout to "fixed", this will prevent the content from overflowing.
In your case:

```
.table.reports_table {
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

When table-layout is fixed, min-width are almost useless on the table elements. So change them to width. In your case:

```
.th[scope="row"] table.reports_table tr td:nth-child(10) {
width: 440px;
}
```

Break the words to fit in the cell for all the td's in the table.
In your case:

```
.reports_table{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```